# how do I convert a very big binary number to decimal?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, binary, decimal

suppose ,I have a binary number stored in an array or a string and the equivalent decimal no. exceeds the range of even unsigned long long int .what can I do in this case?I am using C++

Comment: 1. Choose you poison (language) 2. Tell me how you intend to store very large numbers. 3. Perhaps think why you need to do this - possibly a easier method/design is availlable

Comment: @EdHeal,how would you do that?By the way ,Iam using C++

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: Also are you sure that you need to extremely store large numbers?

Comment: @EdHeal,C++ .....

Comment: What do you want to do with this "number"?

Comment: @EdHeal,Yeah,they may even exceed the range of even unsigned long long int as stated in the question

Comment: apply bitwise operator i.e (number&(number+1))

Comment: Just use [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Iam not sure of how that works,can you please describe/demonstrate it?

Comment: Just google it and read the page

Comment: @EdHeal,is there any way of simplifying the entire process?

Comment: I have pointed you in the right direction - you are going to have to do some reading/experimenting

Comment: @EdHeal,sorry to ask this but ,even after a lot of reading, couldn't figure it out

Comment: Use [GNU Multiple Precision Library](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use c#, it has `BigInteger` in `System.Numerics`.

Unfortunately, you should get useful library( [Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) ),
or implement it by yourself like below code

```
class BigInt
{
public:
    enum IntType{Binary, Decimal };
    explicit BigInt(string number);
    std::string GetBinary();
    std::string GetDecimal();

private:
    std::string m_number;//you should store number as string, so you don't need care maximum number.
    IntType m_type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in my comments - use bitset. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

typedef bitset<200> mybitset; // Or some other number

mybitset convert(const char *s)
{
    mybitset result;
    for (int loop = 0; s[loop]; ++loop) {
        if (s[loop] == '1') result[loop] = true;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    mybitset num_1 =    convert(   "100101011101010100001");
    mybitset num_2 =    convert("110010100001001010100011");

    mybitset result = num_1 & num_2;

    cout << num_1.to_string() << endl;
    cout << num_2.to_string() << endl;
    cout << result.to_string() << endl;

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Or [ideone](http://ideone.com/kuXOmR)

Comment: convert function is redundant. simply use bitsets constructor, e.g.: mybitset num_1 ("100101011101010100001");

Furthermore i can't see why this is an answer because it does not convert into decimal.